# Multiple Table Joins to Improve Performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table structure like this:

Transaction [TransID, ...]

Document [DocID, TransID, ...]

Signer [SignerID, ...]

Signature [SigID, DocID, SignerID, ...]

And the business logic is like this:

- Transactions can have multiple documents
- Documents can have multiple signatures
- And the same signer can
  have multiple signatures in
  multiple documents within the
  same transaction

So, now to my actual question:

If I wanted to find all the documents in a particular transaction, would it be better, performance-wise, if I also stored the TransID and the DocID in the Signer table as well so I have smaller joins.  Otherwise, I'd have to join through the Signature > Document > Transaction > Documents to get all the documents in the transaction for that signer.

I think it's really messy to have that many relationships in the Signer table though and it doesn't seem "correct" to do it that way (also seems like an update nightmare) but I can see that it might be better performance for direct joins.  Thoughts?

TIA!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go with the [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) version. Only reconsider if performance becomes an issue. The other option is a maintenance hazard.

Comment: +1: "also seems like an update nightmare".  Close.  It is an update nightmare.  Indeed, we prevent the update nightmare by normalizing

Comment: +1 - Normalization is the key. Also, extra credit for advising against premature optimization!

Answer (score 4):

Store them as spender suggested in a normalized table.  Add indexes to retrieve your data and see what your performance is like. Although you have multiple-to-multiple relationships, look at them as a percentage of the total.

Comment: +1 for mention indices - that is the correct way to first think about speeding up queries - not using a denormalized structure.  Plus, I'm happy to give you your first upvote!

Answer (score 1):

I'll also point out that storing the transactionid in the signer table won't work as signers are likely to be involved in multiple transactions.

This is such a little, tiny, uncomplicated query that it is unlikely the joins will be problem as long as they are properly indexed.

Comment: In it's current form, signers will "expire" after the transaction is completed or cancelled so they won't be involved in multiple transactions.  However, that is the plan for the future so one day it would be relevant so +1 for that anyway.